# Прямая речь, слова автора, еще слова автора и снова прямая речь

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Как расставляются знаки препинания в прямой речи в таком случае: "Ну, где у тебя тут полотенце? - спросил Петр, и она ответила: - вон в том шкафу, на верхней полочке". Само предложение вымышлено, меня интересует конструкция, как в таких конструкциях расставляются кавычки, тире, двоеточия и запятые.

Answer (score 2):

Это сложное предложение, состоящее из двух частей, причем каждая часть содержит прямую речь. **Постановка знаков препинания независимая.**

"Ну, где у тебя тут полотенце?" ―  спросил Петр, и она ответила: "Вон в том шкафу, на верхней полочке".